# best practice in rails post processing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to rails and I'm beginning to learn the concepts behind MVC frameworks and RESTful architecture. A question that has been a gray area to me is where the logic behind post-processing data might best be handled by, the model, the view, or the controller? Intuitively it makes sense to me that it belongs in the controller, but I wasn't sure what was considered best practice. For example, if I have a resource Student, and I wanted to show their final grade by summing up their total points and dividing it by the total possible points, where would I put that calculation? What if I wanted to calculate the class average? Or their GPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to follow the Fat Model Skinny Controller mantra. Calculated values should be methods in your model. You should use an instance method to calculate the individual student grade and a class method to calculate the total class average.

```
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  POSSIBLE_POINTS = 100

  def grade
     points / POSSIBLE_POINTS
  end

  def self.class_averags
    students = all #or use where to filter results
    total = students.inject(0){ |total, student| total + student.grade }
    total / students.size
  end

end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

All your calculations should be put in models since model handles all business logic. `Controller` as a layer between user that requests such data and view will execute methods from the `Model` and assign retrieved data to a variables that would be later used in `Views` to display that data. Also it would be better to calculate statistics using such gems as [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) and [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) in a scheduled background rake job.